# I can't open my WordPress login from a local Install

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, local

I just changed my WP user password from the Admin area of my local installation (using MAMP here). So right after I saved, everything went blank. 
When I try to go to http://localhost/My-Theme/wp-admin/ I get nothing but a white page (the little MAMP favicon still on the tabs corner of the browser)
However when I go to http://localhost/My-Theme/  I can see my theme running. 
Any ideas?? 
This is really frustrating, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to enter in http://localhost/My-Theme/wp-login.php ? If you also get a white page please check your apache logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should see your apache logs so they will clarify you a bit more because it could be because of many reasons, for example problems with your database. Try to remove plugins and themes so you can see if this works or not, if it works try to add them 1 by 1 and you could see if theme or plugin fails and give this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time ago. This worked for me:

Try renaming the active theme folder (in wp-content/themes). Once renamed, WordPress will revert to using the WordPress Twenty Fifteen theme. Try to enter the login page again.